# Twilio Pay callback post parameters in Python

Tags: twilio, strip

I am trying to use twilio pay in python. I am able to call the pay function properly and the entire card sequence goes very well. However, we are unable to collect the post parameters. I have tried to create a new route and trying to gather the post data but it is coming empty.

```
@app.route('/payment', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def payment():
    resp = VoiceResponse()
    print('paymentmethod')
    shippingid = request.args['shippingnumber'] or 0
    amount = request.args['pay'] or 0    
    print('shippingid',shippingid)
    print('amount',amount)
    resp.say('Calling Twilio Pay')
    resp.pause(1)
    resp.pay(charge_amount=amount,action='/confirmpayment')
    return str(resp)

@app.route('/confirmpayment', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def confirmpayment():
    resp = VoiceResponse()
    multi_dict = request.args
    print(multi_dict)
    print(resp)

resp.pause(1)
return str(resp)
```

'''
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Flask, [`request.args` is the parsed URL parameters](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Request.args). When Twilio makes a webhook request to your application as a POST request, the parameters will be sent as part of the body.

Twilio sends webhook requests as form encoded URL parameters you can use [`request.form`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Request.form) to retrieve this data. Like this:

```py
@app.route('/confirmpayment', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def confirmpayment():
    resp = VoiceResponse()
    multi_dict = request.form
    print(multi_dict)
    print(resp)
```

Comment: It should be documented in the python tutorial. Its very confusing when we have to go back and write a custom function, especially when we are developing a complete workflow.

Comment: Which tutorial were you following? I can advise the team that it could be clearer.

Comment: I was following your twilio pay tutorial. Two more mistakes, 

the pay function doesn't work without the payment_connector parameter.

Comment: [This tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-capture-your-first-payment-using-pay)? When you say two more mistakes, you only seemed to list one. Was there another issue?

Comment: ok
1. My apologies - we need to have this python function updated in the docs for all the languages. So it gets easy for people who are programming. This is an upgrade or modification to the docs and not an issue as such  
2. The pay-connector not mentioned is an issue.  

3. I believe, we should have a default pound sign for each pay function. Its very hard for a user to know if he has finished keyed in 16 digits and may sometimes miss out.  

4.  The expiry mmyy is asked very quickly   
5. User should have an option to start again the pay function

Comment: Hey, I think that the comments on Stack Overflow aren't the best place to talk about this feedback, but it's great you have all of this! Can you email me at philnash@twilio.com with some more detail. Particularly, which tutorial you were following. Thanks!